# Get fields completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the amount of fields completed via Javascript? Like as the user enters input and unfocus the input box I would be able to see, say a 1 in the console if I completed one input field.

I had this code but it doesn't seem to be working

```
  var bad = 0;
$('.form :text').each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") bad++;


});

if (bad > 0) $('.congrats').css("display", "block").text(bad + ' missing');
else $('.congrats').hide();
```

The markup

```
  <div class="form">
 <form name="form">
<input type="text" /><br />
<input type="text" />
</form>
</div>
<p class="congrats"></p><input style="width:100px" value="check" id="a" type="button" />
```

Any ideas? Would i nee AJAX for this?

Comment: Looks fine at first, but please also show a) the DOM/markup b) the unfocus handler that calls this code

Comment: No, you definitely do not need ajax for this.

Comment: Well I'm not sure about the unfocus. But I added my markup @Bergi

Comment: You say you want to do these checks "*when the user enters input or unfocus the input box*". Show us where you attach the event listeners and how you call/execute that code snippet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIDDLE** : http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/3mH6w/1

Just use **keyup** & focus events , it is enough for your needs :

```
     var bad = 0;
var cback=function(){
    bad=0;
     $('.form :text').each(function (i,e) {
        if ($.trim($(e).val()) == "") bad++;
      });
   if (bad > 0) $('.congrats').css("display", "block").text(bad + ' missing');
else $('.congrats').hide();
}
$(document).delegate('.form :text','focus',cback);
$(document).delegate('.form :text','keyup',cback);
```

Comment: What about the unfocus? What about input methods that do not involve keys being released?

Comment: Actually by "unfocus" the OP probably meant the `blur` event. Thanks for the update, but please notice that [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is deprecated since long.